# Change json value without name of key

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am using Editor Datatables to create my website. I need to change a value on client side before send the data to table.

When I click on the submit button, I send a json Object like this `o.data.row_360.vinculos.salario`

I want to do: `o.data.row_360.vinculos.salario /= 100` divide the value by 100.

This is simple, but I can't know what is the third key (row_360), but it is random, like: `o.data.row_25.vinculos.salario`, `o.data.row_44.vinculos.salario`, etc.

When I change the value without know what is the third key name like `o.data.???.vinculos.salario`?

Comment: How many keys does `o.data` have? Only the one or are there others? If there are multiple, what differentiates the one you want to access?

Comment: @Phil o.data have only one key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's only one key in `o.data`, you can retrieve an array of values using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and access the first, removing the need to know the key

```js
const o = {
  data: {
    mystery_key: {
      vinculos: {
        salario: 2000
      }
    }
  }
}

Object.values(o.data)[0].vinculos.salario /= 100

console.info(o)
```

Comment: damn too fast for me

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following snippet to get it working,

```js
const o = {
  data: {
    row_25: {
      vinculos: {
        salario: 2000
      }
    }
  }
}

var d = o.data;

for(let prop in d) {
    if(d[prop].vinculos) {
        d[prop].vinculos.salario /= 100;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(o)
```

Comment: I made your answer into a runnable snippet, hope you don't mind